# C# - How to set service reference configuration in a third party application

Tags: c#, web-services, plugins, app-config

I am currently implementing a plugin for a third party application in C#. The plugin is a library (DLL) and it calls some Web services. So, I created a Service Reference in Visual Studio, which is configured in the `app.config` file of the plugin as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="AuthenticationEndpointImplServiceSoapBinding" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/services/auth"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AuthenticationEndpointImplServiceSoapBinding"
                contract="AuthenticationWebService.AuthenticationEndpoint"
                name="AuthenticationEndpointImplPort" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have another project, that I use for testing the plugin. When I call the service from that project, it works fine, provided I have copied the same configuration to this project's `app.config` file also. But when I build the plugin and run it from within the third party application, I get the following message:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'AuthenticationWebService.AuthenticationEndpoint' in the ServiceModel
>   client configuration section. This might be because no configuration
>   file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element
>   matching this contract could be found in the client element.

I suspect the reason for the error is the fact that there is no configuration file for the third party application. **Do you have any ideas how to work around this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up your parameters(binding, endpoint, etc.) explicitly in your plugin code after reading them from ordinary text file...

Here you will find some example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731862(v=vs.110).aspx